# F#: Namespace not defined when trying to open System.Windows.Forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, f#

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Integrated Shell with the F# CTP (October). Everything works fine, but when I am trying to open **System.Windows.Forms**, VS gives an error: `the namespace 'Windows' is not defined`.

However, it works when I try to open the namespace in **F# interactive**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For F# Visual Studio projects you will need to right click on your project References entry and walk through the Add Reference dialog. F# Interactive includes references to several frequently used assemblies by default whereas F# application projects only get FSharp.Core, mscorlib, System, and System.Core by default.

Answer (score 3):

The System.Windows.Forms namespace lives in the System.Windows.Forms.dll.  You'll need to make sure it's loaded.  In fsi use the following to load it from the gac.

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms";;
```

then you can use as normal

```
let w = new System.Windows.Forms.Form() ;;
w.Show();;
w.Close();;
```